# Android NavController error `no current navigation code`

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-navigation

My layout file presents a list of stores (see screenshot).
[image]

I have set a click listener in my layout file with Data Binding like this:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> storeCallback.onStoreClick(store)}"
```

In my Fragment, I have defined this class like this:

```
class StoreClick(val block: (StoreModel) -> Unit) {
    /**
     * Called when a store is clicked
     *
     * @param store the store that was clicked
     */
    fun onStoreClick(store: StoreModel) = block(store)
}
```

And I am invoking it in the adapter like this:

```
StoreClick {
        // When a store is clicked this block or lambda will be called by MyAdapter
        val action =
                MyFragmentDirections.actionHomeToStoreDetailFragment(it.storeID)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    })
```

Everything works fine **before** configuration change.  However, **after** rotating the device and clicking on a store item in the adapter, the app crashes because of `findNavController` with this error:

> no current navigation code

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I detected the error in AOSP [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F).  However, it is not clear what is happening in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I solved this problem.  Lint in Android Studio Canary was telling me to use a **FragmentContainerView** instead of a `Fragment` in the NavHost activity xml layout.  That's what caused the issue.  Once I changed the NavGraph's enclosing tag back to `Fragment`, it works:
[image]